# Как предустановить параметры запуска окна webdriver в python + selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Не могу найти как правильно предустанавливать параметры запуска для окна webdriver.
Смог только менять окно после запуска. Первым вариантом:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.maximize_window()
```

Вторым вариантом:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.set_window_size(300, 500)
```

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=300,300")

browser_inst = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```

[Доступные аргументы](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)

Comment: Запускается норм, но в высвечивается сообщение в терминале "DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options
  browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = chrome_options)". Что это значит?

Comment: ответ исправил, замените `chrome_options` на `options`. `DeprecationWarning` - предупреждение о функциональности нежелательной к использованию (некая часть функциональности морально устарела (возможно ей на смену пришла более совершенная) и не рекомендуется к использованию.)

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: если ответ оказался полезным, отметьте его как решение, это поможет другим участникам сообщества. спасибо